# How to show json array with conditions using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Hi I have a json array like this

```
var homes = [
    {

        "city": "Dallas",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "75201",
        "NoteNumber": "162500"
    }, {

        "city": "Bevery Hills",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "90210",
        "NoteNumber": "319250"
    }, {

        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "00010",
        "NoteNumber": "null"
    }
];
```

I am displaying them in a `div` using `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="name in homes">
{{name.city}}
</div>
```

I have html `select` tag with options `notenumber` and `null`

Help me how to show cities who only have `notenumber` when notenumber is selected and when null is selected it should show only `null` notenumber cities.

Comment: you can generate select tag with use of `ng-options` and addign current value to `ng-model` in select tag.

Answer (score 1):

Filter your array by another scope var that is bound to your SELECT

```
<select ng-model="selectedNoteNumber">YOUR OPTIONS HERE</select>

<div ng-repeat="name in homes | filter: { 'NoteNumber': selectedNoteNumber }">
    {{name.city}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<select ng-model="NoteNumber" ng-options="homes.NoteNumber as homes.NoteNumber for NoteNumber in homes"> </select>

<div ng-repeat="name in homes">
    <span ng-if="NoteNumber !== 'null'">{{name.city}}</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps